# JavaFXPorts jfxmobile Eclipse: Missing Gradle Tasks in Gradle Tasks View

Tags: javafxports, gluon

In Eclipse, I am using the jfxmobile-plugin within an gradle project which uses gradle 2.9. In the Gradle tasks view are some tasks missing like: android or androidinstall.

Only by changing the gradle version to 2.2 the missings tasks are visible.

My question is: 
What have I to do in order to see the missing tasks in the gradle task view in eclipse for my project without changing the gradle version to 2.2 and keep it by 2.9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have been using the built in Gradle Task window from Eclipse. This window doesn't show all the tasks with higher versions of gradle wrapper.

There is a different Gradle window that shows all the tasks. Select `Window->Show View->Other` and click on Gradle (STS) and select Gradle Tasks. That window will show all the tasks available with the plugin.

[image: Gradle STS]

If you don't find it, you may want to install it from [here](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-44).

Comment: Thank you! Is is the correct answer. Addtionally, I have to mention that I had to convert my gradle project to a gradle (STS) project. But then all tasks are visible.